# The background image doesnt appear everytime using Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Hi I am using the background image in my example. It appears once if I am reloading the page but doesn't appear if I am running the program again.

I have tried setting the image using setBackgroundImage and then render it. It appears first after refreshing the page but doesn't work afterwards.

The fiddle is here — http://jsfiddle.net/wv9MU/6/

```
// create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/jail_cell_bars.png',function() { 
  canvas.renderAll(); 
});


 canvas.setHeight(400);
 canvas.setWidth(1300);
canvas.renderAll();
// create a rectangle object


document.getElementById('1').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
// create a rectangle1 object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'aqua',

  width: 200,
  height: 200
});

// "add" rectangle1 onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);
rect.lockRotation=true;

 canvas.renderAll();   
 });

canvas.setBackgroundImage('C:\Users\131321\Desktop\abc.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));


document.getElementById('2').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
// create a rectangle2 object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 150,
  top: 150,
  fill: 'green',
  width: 50,
  height: 50
});

// "add" rectangle2 onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);
rect.lockRotation=true;
 canvas.renderAll();   
 });
```

Comment: How do I run the program again to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @SumanBogati In the fiddle, when you run the problem will appear.

Comment: The background is loaded at jfiddle everytime I refresh the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's because you're loading a local file, and only when you hit run:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/UsersY321Desktopabc.jpg (index):1
Error loading file:///C:/UsersY321Desktopabc.jpg
```

If I change `line 36` to

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://www.placehold.it/250x250', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

It works every time. http://jsfiddle.net/wv9MU/7/

Try adding `UsersY321Desktopabc.jpg` to your website folders and link it from there.